# PDF Parsing extract CheckBox Fields value

Tags: c#, java, parsing, pdf, checkbox

I have a PDF Documnet that would like to extract Content from PDF and Chackbox and Radio Button types fields value. PDF file have a version 1.4(Acrobat 5.x) and may be genrated from web browser.

CheckBox appear such types in PDF
[image: CheckBox appear such types in PDF]

i want to find checked checkboxes value But no any API and tool is successfully parse to such types of Checkbox fields value and i just extract to text from PDF successfully. and checkboxes didn't recognize to Checked value by APIs.

If any one Knows how to extract and which API should work for such types of PDF files. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those checkboxes active form elements? In that case look for form element handling API methods in the APIs you try, e.g. `AcroFields acroFields = pdfReader.getAcroFields()` in case of iText for Java.

Comment: no, this is not an active form elements. and Acrofields class is not parse it corrected. Is any other option for extract not active forms elements?

Comment: So the boxes most likely are normal page content. Are they some image (bitmap, e.g. in scanned documents), some vector drawing, or are the check boxes characters from some symbol font? It would be easiest if you simply shared the PDF for inspection purposes. A newer question from you seems to point into the scanned-document direction.

Comment: Hi! Any answer to this question? I have the same problem. Basically it's a  PDF form that has been printed out to a solid PDF, so it doesn't recognize the fields. What can we do?

Comment: @mkl - I asked the question again and included a sample file: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25210668/538387

Comment: The comment Chris gave you to that other question most likely is what you will get without employing some expert. It depends on the PDF library of your choice how to implement Chris' idea. I haven't done anything like that before, and as I understand Chris neither has he.